# How can you add clickable text hyperlinks in youtube comments?

Tags: firefox, youtube, text-formatting

My question is how can i add clickable text hyperlinks and by that i mean :

```html
<a href="https://example.com">example</a>
```

BUT in YouTube comments, I know it is possible because of a particular comment on an old
Install gentoo meme video :
[Comment with hyperlink](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VjGSMUep6_4&lc=UghFGoDgNeh1l3gCoAEC)

So far i have tried to use these with no luck :

- [Text](https://example.com)
- <https://example.com>
- <a href="https://example.com">example</a>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT:** I've now realized this is incorrect. [A reply](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VjGSMUep6_4&lc=UghFGoDgNeh1l3gCoAEC.7-H0Z7-DK1g9K3-woaEG6G) to the comment in question reveals the true answer:

> It was a feature on YouTube for a short while, no special method or something. These comments are very rare and I've only seen a couple survive.

#### Original Answer

Recently YouTube rolled out a feature that changes the text of links to YouTube videos. When you link to another YouTube video now, the **link URL is automatically replaced with the target video’s title**.

There is no way to do this manually, or with links to other websites.

For example, the original comment:

> This music: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R9yLJoD2hz8

becomes this automatically:

> This music: [A piece of magicmix](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R9yLJoD2hz8)

Comment: oh I see now, thank you! do you by any chance know how recently this feature was added?

Comment: You're welcome!  I'm not sure when this was added.

Answer (score -1):

Use ahref and make a comment. This will make your anchor text clickable. I hope you like the answer, however, this is my opinion as I follow this thing while posting keywords for seo purpose.